# How does one debug a fortran application where MPI_INIT succeeds but MPI_INITIALIZED returns false?

Tags: fortran, mpi

In my MPI fortran application I have:

```
    call MPI_INIT(ierror )
```

debugging result: 
        ierror .eq. MPI_SUCCESS

immediately afterwards, in the same routine, I call,

```
  call MPI_INITIALIZED(initialzed_flag   , initialzed_ierror )
```

debugging result:   `initialzed_ierror .eq. MPI_SUCCESS` = 0

but: `initialzed_flag .eq. .false`

meaning there was MPI but it wasn't initialized. How do I debug this situation? I am using the intel compiler with intel MPI, ifort version 18.0.5 (2018).

I tried:

```
 export I_MPI_DEBUG=6
 export I_MPI_HYDRA_DEBUG=on
```

but I did not learn anything useful. I am suspecting that the problem occurs at runtime but what is it?

Here is a minimum working example:

```
   program main

   include 'mpif.h'
   integer  error
   integer id
   integer  p

     LOGICAL   initialzed_flag
     INTEGER   initialzed_ierror
  !
  !  Initialize MPI.
  !
    call MPI_Init ( error )
    if (error .ne. MPI_SUCCESS) then
    write(*,*)"MPI_INIT error at", __FILE__, " line ", __LINE__
    stop "Error MPI_INIT"
    endif

c   initialize the error to something other than success
     initialzed_ierror = MPI_ERR_OTHER
     call MPI_INITIALIZED(initialzed_flag   , initialzed_ierror )
     write(*,*)'initialzed_ierror =', initialzed_ierror
     if ( initialzed_ierror .ne. MPI_SUCCESS) then
       write(*,*)"Checking for MPI initialzed failed."
     endif
    if(.not. initialzed_flag)then
       write(*,"(A85, 1x, I3)")"MPI not initialized in " //
 &           trim(__FILE__) // " line ", __LINE__
       STOP "MPI initialzing error"
     else
       write(*,*)"MPI was initialzed"
     endif



 !
 !  Get the number of processes.
 !
    call MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, p, error )
 !
 !  Get the individual process ID. 
 !
    call MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, id, error )
 !  Every MPI process will print this message.
 !
     write ( *, '(a,i1,2x,a)' ) 'P', id, '"Hello, world!"'



  !
  !  Shut down MPI.
  !
      call MPI_Finalize ( error )
  !
  !  Terminate.
       stop
      end
```

The above file was named hello_mpi.F. 
makefile:

```
  all: a.out_mpif90  a.out_mpiifort
  a.out_mpif90:
         mpif90 -f90=ifort hello_mpi.F -o a.out_mpif90    # mimics my error
  a.out_mpiifort:
         mpiifort hello_mpi.F -o a.out_mpiifort
```

the file `a.out_mpif90` seems to mimic my error in the mwe that I am getting with the entire code even though I am using mpiifort.

I also found that:

```
  ldd -v a.out_mpiifort  # gives the same result as the commend below
  ldd -v a.out_mpif90
```

output in the incorrect case (mpirun  -np 2):

```
  MPI_INIT error athello_mpi.F line           15
  MPI_INIT error athello_mpi.F line           15
 STOP Error MPI_INIT
 STOP Error MPI_INIT
```

Comment: Are there any other symptoms? Some computation not working? In which way? You certainly have to tell use which versions of software you use.

Comment: Actually, the `ierror` argument is, IIRC, supposed to be equal to `MPI_SUCCESS` at all. It should be zero to tell you that `MPI_INITIALIZED` itself was successful. Is it zero?

Comment: Also, logicals are compared sing `.eqv.`, not `.eq.`. It probably does not matter. You should show a real [mcve] that is compilable.

Comment: If you think the MPI library installation might be defective (or its combination with your compiler), you need to try as simple test case as possible. Make it and show its complete code and its complete output.

Comment: @VladimirF I have added the compiler information (intel 18.0.5,  2018). Also the `ierror` argument of `MPI_INITIALIZED` returned zero.

Comment: @VladimirF  about .eqv., I actuall used `if(.not. initialzed_flag)then`

Comment: As Vladimir requests a short, complete program along with exactly how you compiled it will be very useful in working out what is going wrong here

Comment: I have added the mwe. It seems there is some problem even though my executable is linking to the light dynamic libraries.

Comment: What is the output of the mwe?

Comment: @VladimirF output added.

Comment: There is a typo in your code! You `MPI_Init(error)` but test `ierror` (note the `I` prefix).

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet, thanks for pointing out. But the error remains. I think this is an environment variable issue. But I was hoping to learn a way to debug such issues in the future.

Comment: Can you please update the code **and** output so we all focus on the real issue?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet done

Comment: So the error is in `MPI_Init()` ?

Comment: First use `IMPLICIT NONE` and then update the program output so that we can be sure it is really up-to-date with the code in the question. `IMPLICIT NONE` **must** be used in all programs that are being debugged here. It is absolutely crucial.

Comment: also, you should `use mpi` instead `include 'mpif.h'` unless you have a good reason to do so.